# Accessing datamembers of template types

Tags: c++, templates, type-deduction

I have several POD structs, all who have a common datafield `uint32_t gID`.

```
struct component1
{
   uint32_t ID;
   //Other data
};

struct component2
{
   uint32_t ID;
   //Other data
};

struct component3
{
   uint32_t ID;
   //Other data
};
```

I would manage the POD structs with a factory class.

```
template <class Component>
class ComponentFactory
{
    public:
    //Activating/Deactivating components
    private:
    array<Component, 65536> m_components;
};
```

Now, the location in the m_components array is not always the same as the components ID. How could I write a function for ComponentFactory to return the ID of a component at some index?
For example,

```
uint32_t ComponentFactory::getIDatIndex(uint16_t index) 
{
    //Grab the ID of whatever component the factory manages.
    return m_components[index].ID;
}
```

Additionally, is it possible to make the ComponentFactory typesafe so that there would not be `ComponentFactory<int>` or `ComponentFactory<char>`?

Comment: ...Have you tried it? The above should work fine. It is duck typing, so there isn't a great way to make it typesafe. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Concepts_%28C%2B%2B%29 was to try and fix that but it didn't ever happen.  There are other ways using typetraits, SFINAE, and/or specialization, but I would personally just add a comment saying "Must be a component" and call it a day.

Comment: `array<Component, 65536> m_components;` where Component are different types and stack memory is limited, simply does not work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you have works fine, after correcting the template syntax.

```
template <class Component>
uint32_t ComponentFactory<Component>::getIDatIndex(uint16_t index) 
{
    //Grab the ID of whatever component the factory manages.
    return m_components[index].ID;
}
```

Comment: I see! I didn't think it would work, seeing how I thought it simply would not know. However, I now see that it deduces at compile-time and therefor will "know" if the requested method/data member is there or not.